# PokiAPI JS Function call using AXIOS/EXPRESS to get pokemon name and image

Tags: javascript, express

Im attempting to gather the pokemon name and image from the pokeAPI as an index page to display both next to each other. Its my first time using API's and havnt really gotten into Promisses yet.
My question is as a very new developer working on a passion project how would I gather both the Name and the image in a call. This uses the following API url:
https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=100000&offset=0

dont mind the security portion.

```
router.get('/all', (req, res) => {
    const { username, loggedIn, userId } = req.session
    // we have to make our api call
    axios(allPokemonUrl)
        // if we get data, render an index page
        .then(apiRes => {
            console.log('this came back from the api: \n', apiRes.data.results)
            res.render('pokemon/index', { pokemon: apiRes.data.results, username, userId, loggedIn})
    })
    // if something goes wrong, display an error page
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('error')
        res.redirect(`/error?error=${err}`)
    })
})
```

Ive tried several things. Attempting to grab the poke number and then using the number as a reference in the github images for the "image" since its a contstant but I couldnt get it to work. As I as I said im very new. :(